# Variable not being assigned value out of function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, nan

This code below replaces "amount" with "NaN".
I feel like it has something to do with the variable being outside of the add function.
Is there any way to get past this basic problem... I feel so dumb right now. Thanks, Matthew.

```js
var x = 5
var y = 4

function add() {
  var x = x + y;
  document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<p onclick="add()">Hello</p>
<p id="amount"> Cacti: 0</p>
```

I'll accept your answer in a bit, I can't accept that fast, sorry.

Comment: There problem here is that you have `var x = 5` and `var x = x + y`, do you see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```html
<body>
        <p onclick="add()">Hello</p>
        <p id="amount"> Cacti: 0</p>
        <script>
        var x = 5
        var y = 4
            function add() {
                x = x + y;
                document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = x;    
            }
        </script>

  </body>
```

Remove var from inside the function, as you don't want to declare a new variable **x**, but use the **x** already declared outside the function.